# how to test x amounts of clients connecting to a php api

Tags: php, api

I just build an api for a software I'm developing, now my question is:
How can I test my api for, for example, 500 clients connecting at the same time.
I need to make sure that I have coded for the fastest and clean as posible.

**edit:**
The php apí is :
cakephp with a cron job requesting info from another api called globalsportsmedia

the app is:
Ios app the connects to the php api.

the test i need to do it:
simulate 5000 people requesting game stast each minute.

Comment: Try pissing off Anonymous.

Comment: You should search google for some Benchmark tools for Apache / YourDatabase (MySQL / ...)

Comment: yeah, but I need to test my code in particular not the whole apache and mysql

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of software you have developed (web app, desktop client, ect), but this similar post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349618/what-tools-can-i-use-to-test-a-rest-api

Comment: *"yeah, but I need to test my code in particular not the whole apache and mysql"* then you have to write it modularly and in such a way that you can profile the individual parts of the application.

Comment: I've build a cakephp api and a ios app, the thing is that the api does  first a cron job to get the information from a api called globassportsmedia, and send i need to make sure that if 5000 people are connecting to this api requesting different game stats the api wont collapse, and that it will be fast too.

Comment: @YairVillar Check the link I posted and see if that will help you.  A quick google search for "Stress Test API" gives some programs out there that can help.  Loader.io seems to have a nice GUI interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parameterized tests I usually turn to [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). It takes a bit of time to set it up, but it will give you great flexibility for stress-testing any kind of service.

Refering to your specific needs, you can

- set up any number of users
- feed API keys to your requests from an external file
- define idle times between requests for users via timers
- randomize timers to have a more lifelike load on your service
- extract variables from responses via regular expressions
- use extracted variables in subsequent requests
- set it up for distributed testing with coordinated requests from several clients

All in all, it's a pretty awesome tool.